# C # Drag and drop both directions

Tags: c#, listbox

I want to drag and drop between listbox and more than one textbox in both directions but when I double click an item in listbox it doubles. I don't know fow to change the drag over latency here is my code for the listbox

1. Mouse Down event

   ```
   private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {


       if (listBox1.Items.Count == 0)
           return;

       int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
       string s = listBox1.Items[index].ToString();
       DragDropEffects dde1 = DoDragDrop(s, DragDropEffects.All);

       if (dde1 == dragdropeffects.all)
       {
           listbox1.items.removeat(listbox1.indexfrompoint(e.x, e.y));
       } ...
   ```
2. Drag and drop event

   ```
   private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {       
   //if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
   //{
   //    string str = (string)e.Data.GetData(
   //        DataFormats.StringFormat);
   //    listBox1.Items.Add(str);
   //}
   }
   ```
3. Dragover event

   ```
   private void listBox1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
     e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
   }
   ```

Comment: Do you have more complete code that you do? Or is this all? I am trying to reproduce your scenario here...